# Function continuous in $[0, \infty)$ and differentiable in $(0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, differentiable in $(0,\infty)$ and $f(0)\geq 0$. Suppose $f’(x)\ge f(x)$ for all x in $(0,\infty)$. Show that $f(x)\ge 0$ for all x in $(0,\infty)$.

I consider $\frac{d}{dx} (e^{-x} f(x)$. This derivative is non negative if $x>0$. I can’t put $x=0$ because the function may not be differentiable at $0$. So how do I conclude? Please help.

Comment: Since $f(0)\ge0$, we may choose $\delta\gt 0$ small enough such that $f'(\delta)\ge f(\delta)\ge0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't say that the function is non-differentiable at zero. Differentiability at zero doesn't make sense, since LHD is not defined at zero.

Since $e^{-x}f(x)$ is a non-decreasing function taking non-negative value at zero, so it is non-negative function $\forall x\in\Bbb R^+$. Further, since $e^{-x}>0\forall x\in\Bbb R$, therefore, we conclude that $f(x)$ is non-negative for all $x\in\Bbb R^+$.

Comment: Thank you for your patient explanation. I was struggling with x=0.

Comment: @LawrenceMano, You're welcome:)